# SQL operation to join 2 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create an SQL operation that allows me to pull the basic information of a user from the users table and then with the results make a second query to the sales table that allows me to get the amount of the products purchased (if any) or null if no products purchased and add that column returned by the second query to the first column with the user data.

I have been trying the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT([Suscription ID])], [Pay go ID]) AS ID, 
    [Name], 
    [City],
    [State],
    [Store1 ID],
    [Store1 Purchases]
FROM Accts
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Store1 ID], SUM([Total#AMT]) AS [Store1 Purchases]
    FROM Store1TX
    WHERE [Store1 ID] = '123456'
    GROUP BY [Store1 ID]
    ) STORE1
ON Accts.[joined_date] = convert(date, '2021/01/07') 
AND 
    (([Suscription ID] IS Not null OR [Pay go ID] IS NOT NULL)
    OR [Store1 ID] is not null
    OR [Store2 ID] IS NOT NULL)
OR
    (STORE1.[Store1 ID] = [Store1 ID])
```

The idea with that is to get the amount of the purchases made by the user with the ID on the Store1 123456 and everything else with null since they do not have an account on that store or do not have purchases but it is just filling all the column with the amount of the purchases of the user with the store1 ID 123456:

[image]

Could someone please help me on how to achieve the query I want to create?
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: We need some sample data. (As DDL+DML or formatted text, not images - please don't use images for data, code or errors).

Comment: What is that `OR (STORE1.[Store1 ID] = [Store1 ID])` doing and does that mean you have two columns with the same name? Also, where is `[Store2 ID]`, do you have a separate table for Store2 (that would be a rather bad design)?